# Sharepoint 2013 Collection Site Error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i'm having a problem in my Sharepoint site while i'm trying to change the style of a new site i made (in a new web application) ..
i tried to make several web applications and sites but there's still the same problem

the site display:

"sorry, something went wrong

error in the application

correlation id: fe17909c-fdc6-60ea-866c-2b80605e4ced"

Answer (score 0):

Please check the logs for detailed exception with given corelationId:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS

After that we can verify the issue.